# Net maui display alert Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. in view model

Tags: c#, maui

Good afternoon, how are you?

I am implementing an application in .NET MAUI, and I am using ZXing to scan product barcodes, when scanning and detecting the barcode, an event is executed in my application and from that event I call a RelayCommand that I have in my ViewModel, within that ViewModel I do a Shell.Current.DisplayAlert(), when that line of code in which the Shell.Current.DisplayAlert() is found is going to be executed, it throws me the following error:

'exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'

Does anyone know why it happens? Here I leave the code.

ScanBarcodeProductPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="StoreSysAppDistribuidoras.Views.Products.ScanBarcodeProductPage"
             xmlns:zxing="clr-namespace:ZXing.Net.Maui.Controls;assembly=ZXing.Net.Maui"
             xmlns:dxc="clr-namespace:DevExpress.Maui.Controls;assembly=DevExpress.Maui.Controls"
             xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:StoreSysAppDistribuidoras.Helpers"
             Title="ScanBarcodeProductPage">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="SeparatorStyle" TargetType="BoxView">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#EBEBEB"/>
                <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="1"/>
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="DragDropTemplateStyle" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Small" />
                <Setter Property="Padding">
                    <x:OnIdiom Phone="0,0,0,0" Tablet="60,0,0,0"/>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#56585c"/>
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="dxc:SimpleButton">
                <Setter Property="IconColor" Value="#404144"/>
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#404144"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="24,8"/>
                <Setter Property="IconIndent" Value="16"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Start"/>
                <Setter Property="PressedBackgroundColor" Value="#e8e8e8"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Fill"/>
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent"/>
            </Style>

            <DataTemplate x:Key="urgentItemTemplate">
                <StackLayout Margin="0" Spacing="0" BackgroundColor="#ffedcc">
                    <Label Style="{StaticResource DragDropTemplateStyle}" Text="Text" TextColor="#e59601"/>
                    <BoxView Style="{StaticResource SeparatorStyle}"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate x:Key="itemTemplate">
                <StackLayout Margin="0" Spacing="0" BackgroundColor="#ffffff">
                    <Label Style="{StaticResource DragDropTemplateStyle}" Text="Text"/>
                    <BoxView Style="{StaticResource SeparatorStyle}"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate x:Key="strikethroughItemTemplate">
                <StackLayout Margin="0" Spacing="0">
                    <Label Style="{StaticResource DragDropTemplateStyle}" Text="Text}" TextDecorations="Strikethrough"
                           TextColor="#989898"/>
                    <BoxView Style="{StaticResource SeparatorStyle}"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <VerticalStackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

            <Label Text="Escanear codigo de barras." x:Name="lblOperation" 
                   FontFamily="ComfortaaBold" FontSize="Title" 
                   VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

            <dxc:DXPopup IsOpen="{Binding IsOpenPopup}"
                         AllowScrim="True" 
                         VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                         Margin="16"
                         CornerRadius="16">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">

                    <Label Text="{Binding PopupTitle}"
                           TextColor="#404144"
                           Margin="24,16,24,14"
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                    
                    <BoxView Style="{StaticResource SeparatorStyle}" Margin="24,0"/>

                    <dxc:SimpleButton Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Text="Crear" TextColor="ForestGreen" 
                                      IsVisible="{Binding IsButtonCreateProductVisible}" Command="{Binding ExecuteActionCommand}">
                        <dxc:SimpleButton.Icon>
                            <FontImageSource Glyph="{x:Static helpers:MaterialDesignIconsFonts.Plus}" Color="ForestGreen"/>
                        </dxc:SimpleButton.Icon>
                        
                    </dxc:SimpleButton>

                    <dxc:SimpleButton Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Text="Editar" TextColor="Yellow" 
                                      IsVisible="{Binding IsButtonUpdateProductVisible}" Command="{Binding ExecuteActionCommand}">
                        <dxc:SimpleButton.Icon>
                            <FontImageSource Glyph="{x:Static helpers:MaterialDesignIconsFonts.AccountEdit}" Color="Yellow"/>
                        </dxc:SimpleButton.Icon>

                    </dxc:SimpleButton>

                    <dxc:SimpleButton Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Text="Eliminar" TextColor="#ff5e61" 
                                      IsVisible="{Binding IsButtonDeleteProductVisible}" Command="{Binding ExecuteActionCommand}">
                        <dxc:SimpleButton.Icon>
                            <FontImageSource Glyph="{x:Static helpers:MaterialDesignIconsFonts.Delete}" Color="#ff5e61"/>
                        </dxc:SimpleButton.Icon>

                    </dxc:SimpleButton>

                    <BoxView Style="{StaticResource SeparatorStyle}" Margin="24,0"/>
                    
                    <dxc:SimpleButton Text="Cancel"
                                      TextColor="#2088ff"
                                      PressedBackgroundColor="#e8e8e8"                        
                                      BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                      Margin="0,0,0,6"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </dxc:DXPopup>

            <zxing:CameraBarcodeReaderView 
                HeightRequest="500"
                WidthRequest="500"
                x:Name="barCodeReader" 
                IsDetecting="True" 
                IsTorchOn="False" 
                BarcodesDetected="barCodeReader_BarcodesDetected"
                
            />


        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

ScanBarcodeProductPage.xaml.cs

```
using StoreSysAppDistribuidoras.ViewModels.PagesViewModels.Products;

namespace StoreSysAppDistribuidoras.Views.Products;

public partial class ScanBarcodeProductPage : ContentPage
{

    ScanBarCodeProductViewModel viewModel;
    public ScanBarcodeProductPage(ScanBarCodeProductViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = this.viewModel = viewModel;
        barCodeReader.Options = new ZXing.Net.Maui.BarcodeReaderOptions
        {
            Formats = ZXing.Net.Maui.BarcodeFormat.Ean13,
            AutoRotate = true
        };
    }

    private async void barCodeReader_BarcodesDetected(object sender, ZXing.Net.Maui.BarcodeDetectionEventArgs e)
    {
        barCodeReader.IsDetecting = false;
        var item = lblOperation.Text.ToString();
        if (e.Results.Any())
        {
            var barCodeReaderResult = e.Results.FirstOrDefault();
            if (barCodeReaderResult != null)
            {
                string barCode = barCodeReaderResult.Value;
                await viewModel.SearchProductByBarCode(barCode.ToString());

                if (viewModel.ScanOperation.Equals(ScanBarCodeProductViewModel.SCAN_OPERATION.SEARCH_PRODUCT))
                {

                }
                else if (viewModel.ScanOperation.Equals(ScanBarCodeProductViewModel.SCAN_OPERATION.CREATE_PRODUCT))
                {
                       viewModel.IsButtonCreateProductVisible = true;
                       viewModel.IsOpenPopup = true;
                }
                else if (viewModel.ScanOperation.Equals(ScanBarCodeProductViewModel.SCAN_OPERATION.UPDATE_PRODUCT))
                {
                       viewModel.IsButtonDeleteProductVisible = true;
                       viewModel.IsButtonUpdateProductVisible = true;
                       viewModel.IsButtonModifyPriceVisible = true;
                       viewModel.IsOpenPopup = true;
                }
                else if (viewModel.ScanOperation.Equals(ScanBarCodeProductViewModel.SCAN_OPERATION.STOCK_COUNT))
                {
                    if (viewModel.ExecuteActionCommand.CanExecute(null))
                        viewModel.ExecuteActionCommand.Execute(null);

                    /*bool allowModifyStock = true;
                    if(viewModel.ProductFound == null)
                    {
                        allowModifyStock = false;
                        await Dispatcher.DispatchAsync(async () =>
                        {
                            await DisplayAlert("Producto no encontrado", "Notifique que se debe cargar el producto.","OK");
                            return;
                        });
                    }

                    if (!allowModifyStock) { return; }

                    Dispatcher.Dispatch(async () =>
                    {
                        string result = await Shell.Current.DisplayPromptAsync("Modificar stock", "Ingrese un valor de stock", initialValue: "0", maxLength: 2, keyboard: Keyboard.Numeric);
                        viewModel.ProductFound.UpdateStock(Convert.ToDecimal(result));
                        await viewModel.ExecuteAction();
                    });*/
                }
                else if (viewModel.ScanOperation.Equals(ScanBarCodeProductViewModel.SCAN_OPERATION.MODIFY_PRICE))
                {
                    bool allowModifyPrice = true;
                    if (viewModel.ProductFound == null)
                    {
                        allowModifyPrice = false;
                        await Dispatcher.DispatchAsync(async () => 
                        {
                            await DisplayAlert("Producto no encontrado", "Notifique que se debe cargar el producto.", "OK");
                            return;

                        });
                    }
                    if (!allowModifyPrice) { return; }

                    await Dispatcher.DispatchAsync(async () =>
                    {
                        string result = await Shell.Current.DisplayPromptAsync("Modificar precio", "Ingrese un valor", initialValue: "0", maxLength: 2, keyboard: Keyboard.Numeric);
                        viewModel.ProductFound.UpdatePrice(Convert.ToDecimal(result));
                        await viewModel.ExecuteAction();
                    });          
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ScanBarcodeProductViewModel.cs:

```
using Application.Products;
using Application.ProductsBarCodes;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;
using StoreSysAppDistribuidoras.Extensions;
using StoreSysAppDistribuidoras.Models.DTOs.Products.Request;
using StoreSysAppDistribuidoras.ViewModels.PagesViewModels.Shared;

namespace StoreSysAppDistribuidoras.ViewModels.PagesViewModels.Products;
public partial class ScanBarCodeProductViewModel : GlobalViewModel, IQueryAttributable
{
    #region [PROPERTIES]
    public enum SCAN_OPERATION
    {
        CREATE_PRODUCT,
        UPDATE_PRODUCT,
        STOCK_COUNT,
        MODIFY_PRICE,
        SEARCH_PRODUCT
    }

    [ObservableProperty]
    private SCAN_OPERATION scanOperation;

    [ObservableProperty]
    bool isOpenPopup = false;
    [ObservableProperty]
    bool isButtonCreateProductVisible = false;
    [ObservableProperty]
    bool isButtonUpdateProductVisible = false;
    [ObservableProperty]
    bool isButtonDeleteProductVisible = false;
    [ObservableProperty]
    bool isButtonStockCountVisible = false;
    [ObservableProperty]
    bool isButtonModifyPriceVisible = false;

    [ObservableProperty]
    string popupTitle = string.Empty;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private ProductInput productFound = null;
    #endregion


    #region [METHODS]
    public void ApplyQueryAttributes(IDictionary<string, object> query)
    {
        if (query.ContainsKey("scanOperation"))
        {
            ScanOperation = (SCAN_OPERATION)query["scanOperation"];
        }
    }

    public async Task SearchProductByBarCode(string barCode)
    {
        var productBarCodeFound = await ServiceLocator.GetService<ProductBarCodeSearcher>().GetByBarCodeAsync(barCode);
        if(productBarCodeFound != null)
        {
            var product = await ServiceLocator.GetService<ProductSearcher>().GetByIdAsync(productBarCodeFound.ProductId);
            if (product != null)
            {
                ProductFound = new ProductInput(product.Id, product.ArticleActivityId, product.Code, product.CostAmount, product.BaseRecord, product.Name, product.Description, productBarCodeFound.BarCode, product.Image, 0, 0);
            }
        }
    }

    private bool productFoundNullOrNew()
    {
        if (productFound == null || productFound.Id == 0)
        {

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }


    [RelayCommand]
    public async Task ExecuteAction()
    {
        if (ScanOperation.Equals(SCAN_OPERATION.SEARCH_PRODUCT))
        {
            
        }
        else if (ScanOperation.Equals(SCAN_OPERATION.CREATE_PRODUCT))
        {

        }
        else if(ScanOperation.Equals(SCAN_OPERATION.UPDATE_PRODUCT) || ScanOperation.Equals(SCAN_OPERATION.STOCK_COUNT) || ScanOperation.Equals(SCAN_OPERATION.MODIFY_PRICE))
        {
            if(productFoundNullOrNew())
            {
                return;
            }

            var product = await ServiceLocator.GetService<ProductSearcher>().GetByIdAsync(productFound.Id);

            if (ScanOperation.Equals(SCAN_OPERATION.STOCK_COUNT))
            {
                if (ProductFound == null)
                {
                    await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Producto no encontrado", "Notifique que se debe cargar el producto.", "OK");
                    return;
                }

                string result = await Shell.Current.DisplayPromptAsync("Modificar stock", "Ingrese un valor de stock", initialValue: "0", maxLength: 2, keyboard: Keyboard.Numeric);
                ProductFound.UpdateStock(Convert.ToDecimal(result));
            }
            //product.UpdateAllFields()
            //await ServiceLocator.GetService<ProductCreator>().Update(productFound)
        }
    }


    #endregion
}
```

I'm having the problem at the moment it enters the

```
 else if (viewModel.ScanOperation.Equals(ScanBarCodeProductViewModel.SCAN_OPERATION.STOCK_COUNT))
```

and from there I execute the RelayCommand of my viewmodel

Comment: you need to look at the `InnerException` for the details

Comment: I test the `Shell.Current.DisplayAlert()` in the code behind and it worked. I debugged it and the Shell.Current is appshell. You can also try to debug it to check the type of Shell.Current.

Comment: Sounds like you are no longer on MainThread. If the app only opens one window (or is on a mobile device), wrap `DisplayAlert` inside `MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`. Or the equivalent `Dispatcher.Dispatch` if you are in code that has access to a Dispatcher.